# JWT returned invalid signature on axios request reactjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

So im trying to create refreshtoken hook in react.
and nodejs with express as my backend.

my backend code looks like this

```
exports.refreshToken = (req, res) => {
  const oldToken = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1]
  if(oldToken == null ) return res.status(500).send({message: "Token is empty"})
  console.log(myJwt.refreshSecretKey)
  console.log(oldToken)
  jwt.verify(oldToken, myJwt.refreshSecretKey, (err, user) => {
    if(err)
    res.status(500).send({
      msg: err || "Error on refreshing your token"
    })
    else res.send({ refreshToken: generateRefreshToken() });
  })
};
```

the problem is *when i try this endpoint with Postwoman (chrome extension) its* **WORK**

but when i try with React + axios the server return is

```
{"msg":{"name":"JsonWebTokenError","message":"invalid signature"}}
```

here is my react code

```
import axios from '../api/axios'
import useAuth from './useAuth'


const useRefreshToken = () => {
    const Auth = useAuth()
    const refresh = async () => {
        console.log(Auth.auth.token)
        const response = await axios.get("user/refresh", {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ` + Auth.auth.token
            }
        })
        Auth(prev => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(prev))
            console.log(response?.data?.refreshToken)
            return {...prev, token: response.data.refreshToken}
        })
        return response.data.refreshToken
    }
  return refresh
  
}

export default useRefreshToken
```

Comment: clearly you're not sending teh same data in your code as you are with whatever the heck "postwoman" is (is that some woke postman alternative?) First step in debugging this is to inspect everything postwoman sends (headers, request body, cookies, etc) and compare it with everything your reactjs code sends (headers, request body, etc)

Comment: lmao yes its just like postman. in postwoman i only send headers authorization

Comment: sure, but check what the differences are regardless (it's a GET, so ignore the bit about request body since there will be no request body)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sending the wrong access token.

What I send in react is the first created accessToken. not the refreshAccessToken